# String length calculation in bits

Tags: string, bit, string-length

In security-related [papers](https://neilmadden.blog/2018/08/30/moving-away-from-uuids) we can often find that a string is called as a *«X-bit length string»*, e.g.:

> *`88cf3e49-e28e-4c0e-b95f-6a68a785a89d`
>
> This is a 128-bit value formatted as 32 hexadecimal digits separated by hyphens.*

This string is a 32-characters UUID with 4 hyphens.
I always assumed that a string length in bits depends on the applied encoding. So, how can I know that this string is a 128-bit string?

How exactly these bits are counted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the characters in that string is a hexadecimal digit. Each hex digit requires 4 bits to represent. 32 * 4 = 128.

(Note: your post says 36, but there are 32 digits there).

The string *itself*, if you're talking about the text representation you've shown, is, as you say, encoding size dependent. In UTF-8, for example, that string is 36 * 8 = 288 bits long.

Comment: Thx, _«Each of the characters in that string is a hexadecimal digit»_ — how can I know that in this case I have to percept this characters as hexadecimal digits?

Comment: It says so right in your question. GUIDs are almost always representated as hex numbers, too.

Comment: _«formatted as 36 hexadecimal digits»_ — it's a quote from a source blog-post. The question was how the author decided that it's hex numbers and not something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - they say that because they wrote it so they know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I know that in this case I have to percept this characters as
> hexadecimal digits?

hex characters include: "123456789abcdef" they are = to "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15" respectively. if you have any string, the characters can be converted to hexadecimal. If you are wondering how:
Each character can be represented by an integer https://www.asciitable.com/
starting at 64 is where the alphabet starts, each character in the string is converted into an ascii integer equivalent and combined to reach a final value.
Hexadecimal will just represent the final value making the final string shorter and only consisting of items from the hexadecimal character table. The UUID/GUID format you are using is using a hexadecimal layout.